# Nginx mixed name and IP based hosts

Tags: nginx

I want to host my sites on separate IP address (due to SNI). I use nginx docker image hosted on AWS EC2. When I set it to:

```
server {
  listen <MY_IP>:80;
  server_name <MY_HOST>.com;
  return 301 https://google.com;
}
```

It never resolves to this part even if the domain DNS A entry is set to `<MY_IP>`. It always resolves to my default setting which is hosted on other IP address:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to mix IP and name based hosts? Is it possible to somehow debug what nginx resolves to what and why?

Comment: Did you check that MY_HOST resolves to MY_IP in DNS? What is the TTL of your A record? Have you tried using your `hosts` file to map the hostname to MY_IP?

Comment: Yes DNS is fine. Maybe there is something special with AWS, I use two elastic IP addresses for one EC2 instance. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191509/nginx-error-99-cannot-assign-requested-address and they say that I should setup my private IP address. But nothing worked so far, any thoughts?

Comment: Try running `nginx -T` to see what configuration is loaded. Or rather would be loaded when performing `service nginx reload`. It might reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the  part from the listen directive in the first server clause then nginx will match requests that contain a Host: header with .com to that first server configuration, and requests with other Host: headers to the second default server configuration.

Also SNI applies to HTTPS/TLS service, not for HTTP service, and it specifically enables serving multiple hosts from the same IP.